# jQuery - Trying to sequentially loop through an array to display only images a certain property value one at a time/Card Deal Challenge

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the Challenge:

The page will have four buttons, one for each suit (Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs
and Spades).

- When the user clicks on one of the suit buttons this will initiate the display of
  the first card in the suit (Ace) above that suit’s button.
- Using a timer set to 1 second, remove the first card and display the second
  card in the suit in the same place the first card displayed.
  o Use the fade in/out effect when switching between cards.
  o Use the timer, set to 1 second, to display all of the remaining cards in the
  suit, one at a time, from Ace to King
- After the King card is removed display a green checkmark image for 1 second.
  o When the checkmark fades away the user can click on the button to deal
  that suit again.
- If the user clicks on a suit button, let’s say Clubs, the user cannot start the deal
  for Clubs over again until after all the cards for Clubs have been dealt and a
  checkmark has displayed.
- All cards should only display above the button for its suit.
- Any of the 4 suits can be displaying at the same time.
- The user can click on any of the suit buttons in any order.

[This is my code so far]

-I can't get each button to start their own suit sequence and I cannot get my images to come through from the images folder. The reference goes like this(example): images/cards/Clubs/Ace.jpg

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function card(name, suit, value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
    };

    var deck = [
        new card('Ace', 'Hearts', 11),
        new card('Two', 'Hearts', 2),
        new card('Three', 'Hearts', 3),
        new card('Four', 'Hearts', 4),
        new card('Five', 'Hearts', 5),
        new card('Six', 'Hearts', 6),
        new card('Seven', 'Hearts', 7),
        new card('Eight', 'Hearts', 8),
        new card('Nine', 'Hearts', 9),
        new card('Ten', 'Hearts', 10),
        new card('Jack', 'Hearts', 10),
        new card('Queen', 'Hearts', 10),
        new card('King', 'Hearts', 10),
        new card('Ace', 'Diamonds', 11),
        new card('Two', 'Diamonds', 2),
        new card('Three', 'Diamonds', 3),
        new card('Four', 'Diamonds', 4),
        new card('Five', 'Diamonds', 5),
        new card('Six', 'Diamonds', 6),
        new card('Seven', 'Diamonds', 7),
        new card('Eight', 'Diamonds', 8),
        new card('Nine', 'Diamonds', 9),
        new card('Ten', 'Diamonds', 10),
        new card('Jack', 'Diamonds', 10),
        new card('Queen', 'Diamonds', 10),
        new card('King', 'Diamonds', 10),
        new card('Ace', 'Clubs', 11),
        new card('Two', 'Clubs', 2),
        new card('Three', 'Clubs', 3),
        new card('Four', 'Clubs', 4),
        new card('Five', 'Clubs', 5),
        new card('Six', 'Clubs', 6),
        new card('Seven', 'Clubs', 7),
        new card('Eight', 'Clubs', 8),
        new card('Nine', 'Clubs', 9),
        new card('Ten', 'Clubs', 10),
        new card('Jack', 'Clubs', 10),
        new card('Queen', 'Clubs', 10),
        new card('King', 'Clubs', 10),
        new card('Ace', 'Spades', 11),
        new card('Two', 'Spades', 2),
        new card('Three', 'Spades', 3),
        new card('Four', 'Spades', 4),
        new card('Five', 'Spades', 5),
        new card('Six', 'Spades', 6),
        new card('Seven', 'Spades', 7),
        new card('Eight', 'Spades', 8),
        new card('Nine', 'Spades', 9),
        new card('Ten', 'Spades', 10),
        new card('Jack', 'Spades', 10),
        new card('Queen', 'Spades', 10),
        new card('King', 'Spades', 10)
    ];

    function ShowCard(start = 0, name = null, suit = null, value = null) {
        if (start < deck.length) {
            displayCard = deck[start];
            if ((name == null || name == displayCard.name) && (suit == null || suit == displayCard.suit) && (value == null || value == displayCard.value)) {
                $("<img>")
                    .attr('alt', 'images/cards/' + suit + '/' + name + '.jpg')
                    .appendTo("#heart,#diamond,#club,#spade")
                    .hide()
                    .fadeIn("slow")
                    .delay("1000")
                    .fadeOut("slow", function () {
                        $("#heart,#diamond,#club,#spade").empty();
                        start++;
                        ShowCard(start, name, suit, value);
                    });
            } else {
                start++;
                ShowCard(start, name, suit, value);
            }
        } else {
            $("<img>")
                .attr('src', "https://www.nicepng.com/png/detail/30-309995_checkboxes-in-google-sheets-checkbox.png")
                .appendTo("#heart,#diamond,#club,#spade")
                .hide()
                .fadeIn("slow")
                .delay("1000")
                .fadeOut("slow", function () {
                    $("#heart,#diamond,#club,#spade").empty();
                });
        }
    }
}

$(function () {
    $("#btnHeart,#btnDiamond,#btnClub,#btnSpade").click(function () {
        ShowCard(0, null, null, null);
    });
});
```

```
This is the HTML: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPimC.png]
```

Comment: Make sure your image paths and filenames are case-sensitive to your code. Also "[This is my code so far]" has nothing there in your question.

Comment: "This is my code so far" - Yeah I was able to fix that and now the code is showing. Can you help?

Comment: [Homework](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/90527), I take it? The description for what problem you're having is currently too vague. Where, specifically, are you getting stuck? To help focus in on the issue, try creating a [mcve].

Comment: I can't get my images to come through from my images folder. I also need the buttons to start their own sequence instead of one button starting all the sequences

Comment: Doesn't look like valid javascript on the function declaration of `ShowCard()`. Is that allowed, to give params default values if they are not passed?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm a noob.

Comment: Well as a "noob" if I'm asking it, and it's your code, shouldn't you have asked yourself that before typing it? Even if it were possible, you can open your browser dev tools to see where the syntax errors reside.

Comment: It's valid. I checked.

Comment: @mardubbles default values in JavaScript functions are 100% valid and used all the time.

Comment: I didn't know that @Rylee but knowing it now can come in handy. I was doing `let param2 = "default value"; if (param2_) param2 = param2_` ... good to learn something.

Comment: There's a few ways you can approach this - one is to have 4 separate "decks" (separated by suit) and then have **each** button show the cards from the relevant "deck". You're already passing through the suit - so use that to pick the relevant deck.

Comment: By having all suits in one array, you will always start at the same card and end at the same one - going through every card each time. You can prevent this by checking the index or checking the "next" card but that seems like it would make it more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing them separately because of what you said @Rylee. Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.